# Format double with five decimals

Tags: java, loops, double, decimal, decimalformat

I'm need to create Java program to find sum of series S = 1 + 1!/x + 2!/x2 + … + N!/xN.

My code is working correctly for the sum but they want my result output to be with five decimals (result - 2.75 to be 2.75000). I'm using **DecimalFormat** for results who are more than five decimals and it work. But how to print results with two decimals - with five?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####"); 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n = scanner.nextDouble();
        double x = scanner.nextDouble();
        double factorial = 1;
        double pow = 1;
        double S = 0;
        double result;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            factorial *= i;
            pow *= x; 
            result = (factorial / pow);
            S += result;
        }

        double finalResult = (S + 1); 
        String formatted = df.format(finalResult); 
        System.out.println(formatted); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I try some combinations like "double with more than two decimals", "double with five decimals" end etc, but I did not know about padding zeros... Sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this format:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");
```